# How to remove escape characters (Symbols or start with \u) from string in Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to remove escape characters from a string, like symbols or special characters that are starting with \u or \x.
Those characters like: \u20ac,\u00a5,\x20ac,\xa5

My Goal: I want to remove those characters from UserName as well users can't be allowed to add those characters/symbols in InputField also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using regular expressions.

Quick example using your input data:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string userName = @"MyAwesome\u20acUser\u00a5Name\x20acWith\xa5ForbiddenCharacters";
       
        // Match anything starting with either \u or \x 
        // followed by between 1 and 4 lowercase letters or numbers.
        const string regex = @"\\(u|x)[[a-z\d]{1,4}";
    
        var sanitisedUserName = Regex.Replace(userName, regex, string.Empty);
    
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Input User Name: {0}\nSanitised User Name: {1}", userName, sanitisedUserName));

        /* Output:
         * Input User Name: MyAwesome\u20acUser\u00a5Name\x20acWith\xa5ForbiddenCharacters
         * Sanitised User Name: MyAwesomeUserNameWithForbiddenCharacters
         */
    }
}
```

[Here is a dotnetfiddle so you can see it running](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WFwKOL).

[Here is a link to Regex101 so you can see how the regex works](https://regex101.com/r/Qg4mvW/1).

You can run the regex replacement function on the input field OnChanged event, or wait until the input is committed before running it, and set the text to the result of the replacement.

Comment: Solution working fine for me @Nick Thank you so much you make my day easy.